# Boot Linux from Linux on embedded board

Tags: linux, boot, embedded, boot-loader, kexec

I'd like to know, is there a way to boot a new Linux system, from a Linux ?
Let me explain : I want to keep 2 systems separated on an embedded board. One system is used to perform tasks at the beginning, and then I'd like to jump on the next system without rebooting and modifying the bootloader config.

I've tried to use kexec, but I still can't make it work. It's saying "Starting new kernel", then "Bye !", but it gets stuck then.

Have you guys a solution to my problem ?

Comment: Separate kernels?

Comment: Kernels must be separated, yes.

Comment: I don't know how to do this without rebooting but, If you install Grub, you can tell it to reboot into another OS once without modifying it's config with the command `grub-reboot`.

Comment: `kexec` is the way to do this - you need to provide more information about how you tried to use it ...